# responsive menu breaks on ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I have a menu I build with responsive design that works good on browsers except the IE7

any idea why this menu breacks on IE7?

link:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107452929/newtest/CWSMainTitle.htm

Comment: what exactly is the problem? In IE I see that the Invitation request tab is extended vertically. Is that the issue?

Comment: please review the menu on IE7 ,it's look different then IE8 or IE9

Comment: Oh ya IE7 shows it differently just seen it. Will try updating my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a **line-height: 0px;** to your nav ul. That solves the issue

Just a suggestion, you can have a easy cross browser compatible navigation bar found here-
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

This exactly does the same what you are trying and also it doesnt run into any issues

Comment: I remove it,but still no change

Comment: You have an issue with the `list style` attribute in css of nav ul and ul. `list-style:none outside none` is not being rendered in IE 7.

Comment: Cdeez - so what is the change I need to make?

Comment: You can see the example in the link which is quite easier to implement

Comment: See the edited solution. That solves your issue. Remember to tick the solution if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that Media Queries are not compatible with Internet Explorer 8 or below.

Refer to this link for Media Queries browser Compatibility: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Also, if I am correct, Internet Explorer 7 is not used on any Tablet/Mobile devices so, why would you have to worry about Responsive Website Design in Internet Explorer 7?

Thanks,
Hope this helps!